# python "and" evaluation sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how python keywords and operators interact with object dunder methods and have encounter a situation I don't quite understand.

**Setup**:
I created two simple classes with the `__bool__` dunder method that I believe should be used when checking for *truthy* conditions. I have them always return true which should be the same behavior as if the method was not defined on the class, but I have added a print statement so I can see when the method is called.

```
class ClassA(object):

    def __bool__(self):
        print('__bool__ check classA')
        return True

class ClassB(object):

    def __bool__(self):
        print('__bool__ check classB')
        return True
```

**Test 1**:

```
if a and b: print(True)
```

The output is what I expected to see:

```
__bool__ check classA
__bool__ check classB
True
```

**Test 2**:

```
c = (a and b)
print(c)
```

The output is **NOT** what I expected to see:

```
__bool__ check classA
<__main__.ClassB object at 0x0000020ECC6E7F10>
```

My best guess is that Python is evaluating the logic from left to right, but doesn't call the `__bool__` method on the final object until needed. (I don't understand why, but I think that is what is happening)

**Test 3**:

```
c = (a and b and a)
print(c)
```

This output agrees with my assumption.

```
__bool__ check classA
__bool__ check classB
<__main__.ClassA object at 0x0000026A81FA7FD0>
```

**Test 4**:

```
c = (a and b and a)
if c: print(True)
```

Further calling `if c` then evaluates the check on the object.

```
__bool__ check classA
__bool__ check classB
__bool__ check classA
True
```

**Question**
Why doesn't an expression such as `(True and a)` fully evaluate inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @blackbrandt You are confusing `and` and `or`, and short-circuiting is not what is happening here.

Comment: @jprebys thank you for that correction, morning coffee hadn't kicked in yet.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `a and b` returns the left hand operand if `a` is falsy and returns the right hand operand if `a` is truthy. There is no need to evaluate the boolean value of `b`.

However, when used in an if statement, it is necessary to check if the entire expression gives a truthy value.